# php won't echo strings that contains \ at last of them

Tags: php

Can some body help me out ?

how I can `echo` this `\` in PHP ?

PHP won't echo strings that contains `\` at last of them

```php
echo "\";
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php please read this documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

> To specify a literal single quote, escape it with a backslash (`\`). To specify a literal backslash, double it (`\\`).

EDIT: As Scuzzy suggests, I too advise reading the whole page.

Answer (score 1):

For a single backslash, it will give syntax error so you can used double backslash.

```
$val = '\\';
echo $val;
```